# (Hex-Rays) How to define C macro?

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, hexrays, idapro-sdk

Im want create reverse macro for constant integers, how i can do it?

Example:

```
#define MU_ITEM(x, y) (x * 512 + y)
```

My goal is make result of number format like: [before](https://image.prntscr.com/image/G3ZHtjWjQsmt7jr6uQzfdA.png) & [after](https://image.prntscr.com/image/HZJY1Bz1QVyhSMCfCoYGtQ.png).

Comment: Don't think you'll get around scripting there ...

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write a hex-rays plugin for that.
You can find examples of the sample plugins [here, in python](https://github.com/idapython/src) or in the samples of the SDK in C++.
[One of these examples](https://github.com/idapython/src/blob/master/examples/vds3.py) inverts if/else in decompiler output with corresponding manipulation of the if statement condition.